# Handling KeyError in xml.dom.minidom when parsing incomplete XML

Tags: parsing, minidom

I am quite new to Python and trying to parse an xml file using xml.dom.mindom.
The xml has some attributes missing under tags. My requirement is that it should atleast try to print the attributes that are present. minidom makes the dict of these attributes and if it doesn't find the key it throws a KeyError. I tried to handle it but not successful in printing the ones that are present.

**Below is my Python Code:**

```
from xml.dom import minidom
try:
 xmldoc = minidom.parse('resources1.xml')
 document = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("xmi:XMI")[0]
 JMSProviders = document.getElementsByTagName("resources.jms:JMSProvider")
 for JMSProvider in JMSProviders:
     try:             #This try block to handle KeyError

         id_name = JMSProvider.attributes["xmi:id"]
         name_id = id_name.value
         j_JMSName = JMSProvider.attributes["name"]
         name_JMSName = j_JMSName.value
         des_name = JMSProvider.attributes["description"]
         description_value = des_name.value
         print "\n ID of JMS is:  %s JMS Name: %s Description : %s " %(name_id,name_JMSName, description_value )
     except KeyError:
         continue

except IOError:
 print ('\n\n Resources.xml file not present at Cell level \n\n')
```

XML as below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xmi:XMI xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:resources.jms="http://www.ibm.com/websphere/appserver/schemas/5.0/resources.jms.xmi" xmlns:resources.j2c="http://www.ibm.com/websphere/appserver/schemas/5.0/resources.j2c.xmi" xmlns:resources="http://www.ibm.com/websphere/appserver/schemas/5.0/resources.xmi" xmlns:resources.mail="http://www.ibm.com/websphere/appserver/schemas/5.0/resources.mail.xmi" xmlns:resources.url="http://www.ibm.com/websphere/appserver/schemas/5.0/resources.url.xmi">
      <xmi:Documentation>
        <contact>abc@xyz</contact>
      </xmi:Documentation>
      <resources.jms:JMSProvider xmi:id="builtin_jmsprovider" name="WebSphere JMS Provider" description="Built-in WebSphere JMS Provider" externalInitialContextFactory="" externalProviderURL=""/>
      <resources.jms:JMSProvider xmi:id="builtin_mqprovider" name="WebSphere MQ JMS Provider" externalInitialContextFactory="" externalProviderURL="">
        <classpath>${MQJMS_LIB_ROOT}</classpath>
        <nativepath>${MQJMS_LIB_ROOT}</nativepath>
      </resources.jms:JMSProvider>
      <resources.j2c:J2CResourceAdapter xmi:id="builtin_rra" name="WebSphere Relational Resource Adapter" description="Built-in Relational Resource Adapter for Container Managed Persistence" archivePath="${WAS_LIBS_DIR}/rsadapter.rar">
        <propertySet xmi:id="J2EEResourcePropertySet_8">
          <resourceProperties xmi:id="J2EEResourceProperty_31" name="TransactionResourceRegistration" type="java.lang.String" value="dynamic" description="Type of transaction resource registration (enlistment).  Valid values are either &#34;static&#34; (immediate) or &#34;dynamic&#34; (deferred)."/>
          <resourceProperties xmi:id="J2EEResourceProperty_32" name="InactiveConnectionSupport" type="java.lang.Boolean" value="true" description="Specify whether connection handles support implicit reactivation. (Smart Handle support). Value may be &#34;true&#34; or &#34;false&#34;."/>
        </propertySet>
      </resources.j2c:J2CResourceAdapter>
      <resources.mail:MailProvider xmi:id="builtin_mailprovider" name="Built-in Mail Provider" description="The built-in mail provider">
        <protocolProviders xmi:id="builtin_smtp" protocol="smtp" classname="com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport" type="TRANSPORT"/>
        <protocolProviders xmi:id="builtin_pop3" protocol="pop3" classname="com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store" type="STORE"/>
        <protocolProviders xmi:id="builtin_imap" protocol="imap" classname="com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore" type="STORE"/>
      </resources.mail:MailProvider>
      <resources.url:URLProvider xmi:id="URLProvider_1" name="Default URL Provider" streamHandlerClassName="unused" protocol="unused"/>
    </xmi:XMI>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `namespaces` in the XML. `getElementsByTagName(tagname)` doesnt work in these case properly. In order to get the Elements using tag names you'll have to use `getElementsByTagNameNS(namespace, tag)` with the appropriate namespaces and you'll get the correct search result.

example:

```
document.getElementsByTagNameNS(resources.jms, "JMSProvider")
```

and so on for remaining search.

You can read more about it on [Element namespaces search](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html#xml.dom.Element.getElementsByTagNameNS)